# HTML Body: data value too large. Can I truncate it in trigger or any other way?

Tags: apex, trigger, email

We are using email to case and users are replaying to customer emails. First when we hit this issue we asked SF to extend size form 32 000 to maximum 131 000 but still for long email chains users hit this error message.

There is agreement that messages can be cut out to fit to the limit but I am struggling how to do that.

Created such trigger:

```
trigger EmailMessage_Trigger on EmailMessage(before insert) {

    System.TriggerOperation triggerEvent = Trigger.operationType;
    switch on triggerEvent {

        when BEFORE_INSERT {
            System.debug('Email Message Before insert trigger');
            for (EmailMessage em : Trigger.new) {
                System.debug('em.HtmlBody.size: ' + em.HtmlBody.length());
                em.HtmlBody = 'a';
                em.TextBody = 'b';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that this trigger is not executed at all as there is no debug log at all.
If it would be executed then email sent to user should have 'a' as a HtmlBody.

Is there any chance to modify HtmlBody before field size validation is run?

Comment: If you look at the Order of execution, all system validations will run including Maximum field length. Hence it will throw error there itself. Therefore `before triggers` won't get executed.

Comment: Email services exist that allows you to utilize an apex class to do what you're looking to do (trim email body). You'd have to create one and have your email address forward to the new email address.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves The issue is that I need to trim outgoing email. For incoming yes I could use email service. Trimming incoming emails is more tricky as I don't know how much to trim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Order of Execution specified in the documentation:

> On the server, Salesforce:
>
> 1. Loads the original record from the database or initializes the
>      record for an upsert statement.
> 2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values. If the request came from a standard UI edit page,
>      Salesforce runs system  validation to check the record for:
>
>    - a. Compliance with layout-specific rules  Required values at the    layout.
>    - b. level and field-definition level
>    - c. Valid field formats
>    - d. Maximum field length
>
> When the request comes from other sources, such as an Apex application
>   or a SOAP API call, Salesforce validates only the foreign keys. Before
>   executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys
>   do not refer to the object itself.
>
> Salesforce runs user-defined validation rules if multiline items were
>   created, such as quote line items and opportunity line items.
>
> > Executes all before triggers.

So in your case, before trigger will never fire. The Maximum Field length validation will fire and exception will be thrown.